# MVC 4 Calendar that works with Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, calendar

MVC noob question.

I searched and searched, but seems like all MVC 4 suggestions point me to some sort of Javascript based Calendar controls.

The problem though for me is that back in .NET 2.0 web form, the calendar control internally works with the CurrentCulture I set in the background. If it's Chinese, the calendar becomes a Chinese calendar, if it's EN-US, it's a regular English calendar.

What calendar control fits in bill in this case?

Much appreciate it.

[Edit] Btw, I see some posts refer to JQuery DatePicker (which can do globalization it seems with some advanced wiring), but I'm more looking for a regular Calendar, without themes and all those junks. I need to apply custom css class over a regular table as we did in .NET 2.0 Calendar?

Comment: Get the jquery calendar anyway, it's the default datepicker in the razor viewengine for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own solution. Still use the traditional webform calendar, no need for extra jquery, jquery globalization and other css.

[Razor MVC return HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173927/razor-mvc-return-html)