# Razor MVC return HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I tried to research a bit, but has not found a proper solution to this.

What I'm trying to do is to have a HTML.Action in a page like so

```
Html.Action("Calendar", "GlobalShared")
```

Inside the action "Calendar", I need to return the result of the html of the traditional calendar control

```
public ActionResult Calendar(
                  String ID,
                   String CssClass,
                   int CellSpacing,
                   int CellPadding,
                   String BorderWidth,
                   String ShowGridLines,
                   String ShowTitle,
                   String DayNameFormat
            )
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar cal = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar();
            cal.ID = "MyCalendar";
            cal.CssClass = "month-view";
            cal.CellSpacing = 0;
            cal.CellPadding = -1;
            cal.BorderWidth = 0;
            cal.ShowGridLines = false;
            cal.ShowTitle = false;
            cal.DayNameFormat = System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayNameFormat.Full;

        }
```

How can I do this? Btw, I use HTML.Action is because I read that it returns a html string, is that correct or should I be doing some other ways?

Thanks

Edit. Before I attempted this in a controller, I tried the following code in a view .cshtml and it works, but I prefer to move the code into a controller

```
  @{
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar cal = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar();
                    cal.ID = "MyCalendar";
                    cal.CssClass = "month-view";
                    cal.CellSpacing = 0;
                    cal.CellPadding = -1;
                    cal.BorderWidth = 0;
                    cal.ShowGridLines = false;
                    cal.ShowTitle = false;
                    cal.DayNameFormat = System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayNameFormat.Full;
                    cal.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(Html.ViewContext.Writer)); 
                }
```

Edit #2.  The reason I want to use that in a controller is because if in the future, i want to hook up an event say "DayRender", I can do it in the controller.  I can not do the same in a view without polluting the view page.

Comment: This is not correct.  `Html.Action` generates the HTML code for a link whose URL corresponds to an action method in a controller.  It isn't used to craft custom HTML strings.  If you need to build HTML, you build it in the view itself.  Trying to render in-memory some old web controls and output the rendered HTML is going to create very convoluted and messy code, and probably won't end up working at all.

Comment: David, I can not find a calendar control out there that works out of the box with Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, such I simply want to use Calendar Control to output the correct html to the page.

Comment: I don't think there's any way of using Web Forms controls in MVC, so if you're absolutely _required_ to use a Web Forms control then you're out of luck.  You could perhaps construct your own calendar.  Or a Google search for "ASP.NET MVC Calendar" returns (expectedly) many results.  The Telerik offerings are usually particularly good.

Comment: @David. Please see my edit above. I was able to do this in a view .cshtml, it worked okay. So now I just wanted to move that into a controller.

Comment: jqgrid has what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Thanks guys. I figured out. Basically, I need to use  @{Html.RenderAction(..)} and in the action itself, use StringBuilder/StringWriter and then return Content(...). Code below

In View

```
 @{Html.RenderAction("Calendar", "GlobalShared");}
```

In Controller

```
[ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult Calendar(
            )
        {

            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar cal = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar();
            cal.ID = "MyCalendar";
            cal.CssClass = "month-view";
            cal.CellSpacing = 0;
            cal.CellPadding = -1;
            cal.BorderWidth = 0;
            cal.ShowGridLines = false;
            cal.ShowTitle = false;
            cal.DayNameFormat = System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayNameFormat.Full;
            cal.DayRender += new System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventHandler(CalendarDayRender);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb))
            {

                System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
                cal.RenderControl(writer);
            }
            String calHTML = sb.ToString();
            return Content(calHTML);
        }

        private void CalendarDayRender(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {

            e.Cell.Text = "";
            if (e.Day.Date == System.DateTime.Today)
            {
                e.Cell.CssClass = "today";
                System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl h3 = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("h3");
                h3.InnerHtml = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("JTG_DateTime", "JTK_Today") + " " + e.Day.DayNumberText;
                e.Cell.Controls.Add(h3);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply move your code

```
@{
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar cal = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar();
                    cal.ID = "MyCalendar";
                    cal.CssClass = "month-view";
                    cal.CellSpacing = 0;
                    cal.CellPadding = -1;
                    cal.BorderWidth = 0;
                    cal.ShowGridLines = false;
                    cal.ShowTitle = false;
                    cal.DayNameFormat = System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayNameFormat.Full;
                    cal.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(Html.ViewContext.Writer)); 
                }
```

in a view and return that View from your Calendar Action.

```
public ActionResult Calendar(
              String ID,
               String CssClass,
               int CellSpacing,
               int CellPadding,
               String BorderWidth,
               String ShowGridLines,
               String ShowTitle,
               String DayNameFormat
        )
    {
       return View("Calendar");
    }
```

You can either create a ViewModel or use ViewBag to transfer these values from Calendar Action to your newly created View

Comment: Thanks #UmairP. I thought about that. The reason I want to move into a controller is because in case in the future I want to add events such as "DayRender", I can perform that in a controller. By doing that in a partialview, I lost that ability

Comment: I am not saying that you should do HTML.RenderPartial. You should use HTML.RenderAction and call your action from where ever you need in your application.